# Access Map<K, V> values in DTO from JSON?

Tags: angular, typescript, collections, frontend

I have got 3 DTO-s inside eachother like this:

```
export class firstDTO {
    public data: secondDTO;
}

export class secondDTO{
    public data: Map<Color, thirdDTO>;
}
```

After I receive the JSON from the backend, I can print it to the console, but can't access the values inside the Map. I'm getting undefined errors.

```
private getJsonData(): void {
this.service.getJSON()
  .subscribe((jsonData: firstDTO) => {
    this.things = jsonData;
  });
}
```

They way I would like to reach a property of Color, is like this:

```
this.things.data.data.key[0].property
```

Of course it won't work like that, so I would like to ask for help regarding this issue.

Comment: what is the output of jsonData? Can you show?

Comment: Added image to the post

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your retrieved json is same as type of first dto 
and you know the key of third dto you can get it like below, as in print method.
else just iterate data.first.second it will return the map as some key and value as thirddto.maps can be iterated using foreach.

```
export class AppComponent {
print(data:first){
console.log(data.first.second.get('color'));
}
}

class first{
first:second;
}

class second{
second:Map<string,third>;
}

class third{
third:string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no `Map` objects in JSON.  It looks like you instead have an object that is intended to be indexed with strings of the form `LocationDTO(...)`.  You would declare this as follows:

```
export class secondDTO{
    public data: {[s: string]: thirdDTO};
}
```

If `key[0]` is a string of the proper form, then you would use `this.things.data.data[key[0]].property` to access a property of the third DTO.  Note the additional square brackets where you had a dot.

Comment: I can't use [key[]] for some reason. VS code marks it as an error. I added a picture about the backend. There are 3 HashMaps inside eachother. Should we change the backend json format to a different structure?

Comment: What error do you get from the `[key[0]]` syntax?  Where do you get `key` from?  Please make an effort to provide the information we need in order to help you, otherwise we may not find it worth our time to follow up on this thread.